# How to play a audio/mpeg file in html from a POST response in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, post

I'm just learning pure js http requests here so i don't care if my api key is exposed. I have a POST response that outputs audio/mpeg files. When i check the api endpoint in insomnia it automatically gives me an audio controls to play.

I already have a button here,

`<button id="outputSound" class="focus-visible-style">Play</button>`

I then do this in js,

```
async function postTTS(url, data2) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'xi-api-key': API_KEY_EL,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data2),
  });
  return response.json();
}

voice.addEventListener('click', () => {
  postTTS(
    `https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${bellaVoiceId}`,
    body
  ).then((data2) => {
    return data2;
  });
});
```

but got this error

'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data'

i've tried doing,

```
voice.addEventListener('click', () => {
  postTTS(
    `https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${bellaVoiceId}`,
    body
  ).then((data2) => {
    const audio = new Audio(data2);
    audio.play();
    console.log(data2);
  });
});
```

but still got the error,

i don't know how to convert the audio/mpeg file to be something that js and html understands , any thoughts on this?

Comment: Look in the network tab to see what is being returned from that request.

Comment: @Popnoodles its returning some weird text here : '//tQxAAABXQDHYCMYCEhE2U0MI2UARIrLS2yMyCSYnDFgnPiBRwMZ9YEOcH4f6C' that goes on for 11710 characters.

Comment: That's looks like a file, not JSON. Someone has answered already

Comment: @Popnoodles yup, thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Since the response is a MPEG file, convert it to a blob, then use `URL.createObjectURL` to get a URL that can be passed to the `Audio` constructor for playing it.

```js
fetch(`https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${bellaVoiceId}`, {/* options */})
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        new Audio(url).play();
    });
```

Comment: it still returns the same error

Comment: actually nevermind it still returns the error because my function was returning it as JSON still, thanks ily <3